# Access to path is denied on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to make a multiple file upload function (last example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478971.aspx )

I changed the upload location to

```
"httpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/")
```

and when I upload a file, it says

Access to the path "D:...." is denied.

I cant set permission for the folder on the server for some reason. what else can I do?

All help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your asp.net account `{MACHINE}\ASPNET` does not have write access to that location. That is the reason why its failing.

Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity.

-Right click on downloading folder `Properties > Security Tab > Edit > Add > locations > choose your local machine > click OK > Type ASPNET below "Enter the object name to select" > Click Check Names Check the boxes for the desired access (Full Control). If it will not wok for you do the same with Network Service`.

Now this should show your local `{MACHINENAME}\ASPNET` account, then you set the write permission to this account.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's actually on a server. (not c:/inetpub) if I go in to the ftp site and right click the folder, it says "This server does not support changing file permissions" is that suppose to be normal?

Comment: You need to log in with different user who have permissions to do that. or ask administrator to give the access for that particular user.

Comment: I am using the admin account. is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: have you ensured imagepath isnot a folder??

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: is that path a valid path.it should not be path of folder. should be path of file

Comment: I intend to put the files in the "images" folder. that means the file would be "images/abc.jpg" would it be the right path?